# How to combine various usercontrol classes in multiple configurations?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm building a visual component framework in vb.net wpf. After I got done with the most basic elements (like buttons effects and checkboxes), I started making compound elements based on various combinations of the basic elements (like checkboxes with text or buttons with various types of response effects).

The um.. inconvenience I ran into was that I seem to be writing the same code over and over again. Most of the basic elements have xaml accessible properties and most of them need to also be accessible through the compound elements.

Just to give an example of the situation -

I have a basic element that gives whatever container its in a buttonized look with definable depth and color properties.

I have a basic element that gives whatever container its in mouseover/click type highlight effects.

Then i was making a basic button with the combination of these 2 but now, if i want to have the buttonization properties to be accessible in the button, I have to rebuild and rebind the same buttonization properties again in the button which is no shorter than creating the exact same functionality in the button in the first place.

I looked around and thought that maybe interfaces might be my answer but it seems that they don't actually define any methods or anything and just create an obligation to the implementing class to have those methods.

So does anybody know of a .net concept to aid with this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to go the same way WPF does it. By using some inheritance hierarchy. For example all WPF buttons inherit from ButtonBase where all common properties and logic are defined.

The other way is to use WPF Behaviours and Attached properties. It allows you to attach specific logic to WPF controls. However in this case you will have troubles to communicate between different behaviours attached on the same control.

Unfortunatly I can not give you a better answer as I don't know your motivation to rewrite existing controls.